# MySQL: MAX(COUNT(*)) -- error 1111

Tags: mysql, count, max

I am new to MySQL; I am using SAS, and my brain is twisted in SAS style.
So, even I think I saw people asked questions similar to mine, I still cannot make sense out of the answers they received. I apologize for it.

I have 2 tables:

film_category containing columns:

```
category_id,film_id,
```

, film_actor containing columns

```
actor_id, film_id.
```

I joined them on film_id

. The question is:
    What are the most popular actors in each film category?
There are 16 categories, 200 actors, 1000 films.

```
SELECT film_actor.actor_id,MAX(COUNT(actor_id))
FROM film_actor JOIN film_category 
ON film_actor.film_id = film_category.film_id
GROUP BY film_category;
```

Sure enough, I've got error 1111, as soon as I added MAX...
Please let me know, if my question is not clear.
Thank you!
-Vera

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT fa.actor_id, MAX(COUNT(fa.actor_id))
FROM film_actor fa JOIN
     film_category fc
     ON fa.film_id = fc.film_id
GROUP BY fc.film_category;
```

This is invalid, because you cannot nest aggregation functions.

To do what you want, use a subquery and clever aggregation:

```
select film_category, max(numfilms) as maxnumfilms,
       substring_index(group_concat(actor_id order by numfilms desc), ',', 1) as actor_id
from (select fc.film_category, fa.actor_id, count(*) as numfilms
      from film_actor fa join
           film_category fc
           on fa.film_id = fc.film_id
      group by fc.film_category, fa.actor_id
     ) ac
group by film_category;
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately something is wrong here. Maybe I've made a typo, which I can't see...

Comment: In the meantime I was able to find overall maximum value. Please see below. Now my question is how to modify this code to find maximums by film_category?                                     mysql> SELECT c FROM
 (SELECT COUNT(*) as c, actor_id FROM
 film_actor JOIN film_category ON
 film_actor.film_id=film_category.film_id
 GROUP BY actor_id
 ) tmp 
 ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1;
+----+
| c  |
+----+
| 42 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)

Comment: @Vera . . . If you set up a SQL Fiddle, we can figure out what is wrong with the query.

Comment: Please advise what should I do. Thank you. - Vera

Comment: @Vera . . . I did.  Set up a SQL Fiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com) so the code can easily be tested.

Answer (score 0):

Most occurring actor:
SELECT category_id AS cid,
    (SELECT actor_id FROM 
film_actor JOIN film_category 
  ON  film_actor.film_id = film_category.film_id
        WHERE category_id = cid 
        GROUP BY actor_id
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 0,1) AS topActor
FROM film_actor JOIN film_category 
  ON  film_actor.film_id = film_category.film_id
GROUP BY category_id ;